# Least Squares Solution for the Closest 3D Point to a Set of Planes

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, regression, least-squares, plane-geometry

I have a set of 2D planes in 3D space, each defined by a point on the plane and a normal vector to the plane (so vertically oriented planes are allowed). I need to find the point in 3D space that has the minimum sum of squared distances to all the planes. What's the right way to formulate this problem as a least squares regression?

(The regression is underspecified for fewer than 3 mutually intersecting planes.)

It would be even more ideal if I could use RANSAC to discard outliers, because the planes are unlikely to all intersect at a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of any of the planes can be written as
$$ \newcommand{x}{\mathbf x}\newcommand{v}{\mathbf v}\newcommand{c}{c}
\x \cdot \v_i + \c_i = 0 $$
where $\x$ is the set of coordinates of a point on the plane,
$\v_i$ is the normal vector to the plane, and $\c_i$ is a constant.
You can find $\c_i$ by evaluating $-\x \cdot \v_i$ where $\x$ is set to the coordinates of the known point on the plane.

The distance from a point $\x$ to the plane is
$$
\frac{\lvert\x \cdot \v_i + \c_i\rvert}{\lVert\v_i\rVert}
$$

and the square of the distance is therefore
$$
f(\x) = \frac{1}{\lVert\v_i\rVert^2}
\left((\x \cdot \v_i)^2 + 2 c_i (\x \cdot \v_i) + c_i^2\right).
$$

This comes down to a quadratic polynomial over the coordinates of $\x.$
Add together the polynomials from all planes and you still have
a quadratic polynomial over the coordinates of $\x$, which is to be minimized.

If we represent the vectors by column vectors of coordinates,
then $(\x \cdot \v_i)^2$ is $(\x^T \v_i)^2$ in matrix notation,
and
$$ (\x^T \v_i)^2 = (\x^T \v_i)(\v_i^T \x) = \x^T A \x $$
where $A = \v_i \v_i^T.$
So $f(\x)$ is a quadratic form, which may help.

Comment: Much appreciated, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note that the absolute value on $\lvert\x \cdot \v_i + \c_i\rvert$ make the distance an unsigned distance, but the solution works just as well if you omit the absolute value and use the signed distance instead. For computation I usually prefer the signed distance.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying! I was getting negative distances, and apparently I didn't see the absolute value bars :-)

Comment: Follow-up question: I'm using this to find the optimal translation mapping one point cloud to a similar point cloud. Solving the quadratic form for $x$ does give the right solution much of the time -- at least it gives a good estimate, and then I can move the query points closer to the solution, find the closest point to each query point again, then solve the quadratic form again. But in some cases, this converges slowly, and/or gives the wrong solution -- I think when there are many planes that are almost normal to the vector between the query point and the point on the plane. (ctd...)

Comment: I think the problem is that the quadratic contribution to $A$ of these "glancing planes" has very low curvature (represents a very "wide" paraboloid), and/or outliers quadratically throw off the solution. To my untrained eye, $A$ looks like a Hessian. How can I find a subset of the polynomial contributions of all planes that gives the sharpest, most self-consistent least squares solution, minimizing not just the whole quadratic form, but the error of as many terms from individual planes as possible? (ctd...)

Comment: I'm thinking something like RANSAC applied to a measure of curvature derived from the polynomial contribution to $A$ (to reject planes that are almost parallel to the direction of movement of the query points towards the least squares solution) might solve the "glancing planes" problem. And RANSAC may also be useful in eliminating outliers that are quadratically pulling the solution in the wrong direction. I'm not sure how to turn this algorithm into a RANSAC algorithm though. Any thoughts would be very much appreciated!

Comment: There seem to be many additional considerations in the underlying problem. It is not obvious to me how you define planes to set up a translation mapping. I think it may be time to ask a question about how you can apply distance-from-planes to the translation problem. Perhaps there is a way to assign weights to the planes that would discount the influence of the "glancing" planes without needing to identify outliers--but I really don't know. A new question might give you a better chance to attract a new audience with better ideas than mine.

Comment: I have two point clouds that are offset only by translation, but also include sampling noise. Finding all nearest neighbors in the second cloud for each point in the first cloud, and then averaging the vectors from each point to its nearest neighbor to try to find the translation mapping the first point cloud to the second, gives poor alignment.

Comment: I have an estimate of the surface normal for each point, and the planes I'm using are orthogonal to the surface normal at each point, and pass through the point (so the planes are a local estimate of the surface).

Comment: I formulate the translational registration problem as follows: I find the vector from each point in the first cloud to the nearest neighbor in the second cloud, then interpret this vector as a point, centered about the origin. This point is assumed to be a point on the surface of the manifold sampled by the second cloud. The local shape of the surface is estimated by a plane passing through this point, using the surface normal estimate for the point to orient the plane.

Comment: Now finding the point that is the minimal sum of squared distances to all planes generated in this way gives a translational offset that should optimally translate the first point cloud to align with the second. It actually works really nicely, when it works. (Sometimes I have to move to the least squares solution, and then repeat the process multiple times until convergence, because the nearest neighbor search is only an estimate of the final location of each point in the first cloud after translation to align with the second cloud.)

Comment: However solving the quadratic form quadratically amplifies outliers, and struggles in some situations, I think when there are a lot of these planes where the plane is nearly "coincident to" the optimal translation vector mapping the first point cloud to the second (I called these "glancing planes"). I suspect that these glancing planes have high error, since any distortion in surface normal will strongly affect the solution of the quadratic form. Summing many of these glancing plane contributions together seems to "flatten" the quadratic form, so that the turning point is much more indistinct.

Comment: Sorry for the complex explanation, and you're right, this probably needs a separate question -- but it's a lot to describe, and anytime I have asked such a specific question in the past, I have received very few if any responses (the more generic problem formulations seem to get more answers). Any further thoughts would be appreciated, but if it doesn't make sense, no worries! Thanks again for your original answer, it helped me make progress.

Comment: A better solution would actually be Gaussian-smoothed cross-correlation, since that would give a local maximum corresponding to the optimal translational offset mapping the first point cloud to the second, but this is expensive in time and space, even if using the FFT. This is why I opted for the nearest neighbor approach that led to this question.

Comment: Why not take the center of mass of each cloud and the vector between these centers as the translation vector?

Comment: because the spinning LiDAR sensor that produced the point clouds has a limited field of view. I have already corrected for rotation using an eigenvalue method, but if the sensor orientation changed between the two frames, there may be a significant number of points visible in one frame but not the other, and vice versa (e.g. one frame may contain a bunch of floor points while the other contains a bunch of ceiling points). This will throw off the centroid.

Comment: Won't it throw off everything else too? This problem gets more interesting (and not in an easy way) at every turn!

Comment: Not necessarily. Each point cloud is a grid-sampled approximation of the visible surfaces around you. There is distance noise, and the sampling grid in general will not line up between two frames, hence the use of nearest neighbor search to pair points in one cloud with the other. If two point clouds share an overlapping sub-manifold, you can ignore the non-overlapping parts (if you can identify them, e.g. if the nearest neighbor distance is greater than some threshold).

Comment: The overall approach is ICP (Iterative Closest Point). There are many variants with different strengths and weaknesses. I decided to create my own from scratch, which meant figuring out every step from first principles. For rotational registration, I'm using nearest neighbor search followed by "Rapid calculation of RMSD using a quaternion-based characteristic polynomial" [Theobald 2005], which works quite robustly; then I try to register translationally using the least squares formulation you pointed me at. When it works well, the results are excellent, but when it doesn't, it really fails.

Comment: OK, I think I had a misconception of the magnitude of the translation. If you are just correcting for a kind of "drift" or noise which is (usually) smaller than the distance between points in one cloud, then nearest neighbor will (usually) find the point that your particular point traveled to. Interesting. I still think that you might be able to summarize this in a question that could attract more interest (and maybe better answers).

Comment: Well I'm trying to solve this for a head-mounted LiDAR, so at biking speeds you could move 40cm in a single 20Hz frame, and you could turn your head a few degrees during that time. The distance noise of the sensor is about 10cm. I'll see if I can formulate a better question, but you're right, it's a complex and multifaceted problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a single plane, say defined by $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y0)+c(z-z_0) =0$ (this is the normal vector point form). What is the (signed) distance from a point $(x,y,z)$ to it? Well, if the vector $(a,b,c)$ has unit length, it's exactly the left hand side of that equation (it is the appropriate scalar projection onto the normal vector). This is just a linear function in $(x,y,z)$.

This suggests the way to solve the original question: We should do is rescale the normal vectors to have unit length then find the least square solution of the equations defining membership in the planes.